# Set CSS of an span tag on sibling hover

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-selectors

Hey does anyone know how I would accomplsh this with pure css.

```
<a id="link"><span>Some Text</span></a>
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

Make the spans "Some Text" a certain color when someDiv is moused over.

Not sure if this is possible.  Thank.

Comment: FWIW, this is pretty trivial to do if you are using a JS library like jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Due to the way CSS selectors work, there's no previous sibling selector. So with your existing markup you can't use pure CSS to do it.

If the link were to come *after* the div, however:

```
<div id="someDiv"></div>
<a id="link"><span>Some Text</span></a>
```

The selector to use would be `#someDiv:hover + #link span`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be possible if you have a parent element to associate the css hover class with. For example:-

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="someDiv"></div>
<a id="link"><span>Some Text</span></a>
</div>
```

& den use the following css.

```
#link
{
position:absolute; /*This is to ensure the hover is activated only on the someDiv div & as absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow of the document*/
/*You can position this anchor tag wherever you want then */
}
#parent:hover > link > span
{
color:#000;
/*enter code here/*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure css? Working in all browsers? Not possible in this structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, assuming these two elements share the same parent and `a#link` is the first child of that parent element.

```
#parent div#someDiv:hover ~ a#link:first-child span {
   color: blue;
}
```

[IE6 doesn't support it](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30), but if you can live without IE6 (and you really should, IMO), you should be okay.

Comment: The general sibling selector doesn't look *around*, only *after*. So for `<div /><span /><div />`, `span ~ div` only picks up the last `div`.

Comment: The [tilde `~` general-sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) removes the requirement that the two elements be immediately *adjacent* siblings, but it doesn't remove the necessity that the `div` appear *before* the `a` in the mark-up.